# python3: replace one of duplicate sting items in a list with another string as:

Tags: python-3.x, replace

There are several duplicate srting items in my list. I want to change one of these items with another string item. For example:

`a = ['b','c','d','b','b']`

I want to change 'b' with index 3 with 'x'

`a = ['b','c','d','x','b']`

Comment: OK...and what is the logic here?  Why change the second duplicate value?

Comment: This is an example. The first, the second, or the third one is no different. It is important to replace just one of duplicate items with another string item.

Comment: I find the index of the item that is supposed to be replaced depending on the code I intend to write with the if and for loop.

Comment: what is the result of ['b','c','d','b','b','c','c'] will be ['b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'b', 'a', 'x'] ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically list operations are:

- `a.pop(idx)` (Will pop item on index `idx`)
- `a.insert(idx, val)` (Will insert value of `val` at position `idx`)

YET, this is a really badly defined programming problem, with lots of open questions:

1. can the duplications occur more than 2 times?
2. shall the replacement be done only for the 1st item?
3. shall the replacement be done with constant character, or maybe a sequence?

Smells like homework. IF so, Please Do it without stackoverflow....

Comment: Thank. Yes, this is a homework. But I did my homework with a.pop and a.insert. I asked to learn alternative methods, not to solve it.  ;-)

Comment: @H.RSh For future reference: Please always include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, so SO users don't waste time on the same approach you already have. And if you have a working code that you think needs improvement you should head to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please carefully read their FAQ to see the requirements there.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments it looks like you don't care if all duplicates are replaced. So you could do this in one line with the following:

```
a = ['b','c','d','b','b']
new_a = [item if len([c for c in a[:index+1] if c == item]) == 1 else "x" for index, item in enumerate(a)]

print(new_a)

['b','c','d','x','x']
```

If you really only want to update the 2nd instance the following works in one line also:

```
a = ['b','c','d','b','b']
new_a = [item if len([c for c in a[:index+1] if c == item]) != 2 else "x" for index, item in enumerate(a)]

print(new_a)

['b','c','d','x','b']
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Yousif, I had originally tested it with the starting list named "t"